# Mensajes de error en Wordpress después de actualizar a PHP 7

Tags: wordpress, php7

Tengo un sitio web manejado con Wordpress. Hoy he actualizado el **PHP en el hosting a la versión 7**.

Me pregunto si en PHP 7 **no son reconocidas las opciones de debug apagado de Wordpress**.

Antes, y ahora, tengo esto en el archivo `wp-config.php`:

```
define( 'WP_DEBUG_LOG', false );
define( 'WP_DEBUG', false);
```

para indicar que no me cree archivos de debug ni me muestre errores en pantalla.

**Antes de pasar a PHP 7 no había ningún problema**, los mensajes de error o las advertencias no se mostraban en la pantalla (pues es algo desagradable, sobre todo para los usuarios... y peligroso, porque se muestran datos internos del servidor), sólo los escribía en el `error_log` del mismo PHP. Pero ahora acabo de entrar a una de mis páginas y veo un error como este en la parte de arriba:

> Warning:
>   include_once(/home/site/public_html//user/LogTrace.class.php): failed
>   to open stream: No such file or directory in
>   /home/site/public_html/wp-content/thesis/... on line 22

Fui a revisar si algo había cambiado en `wp-config.php` y no, todo sigue igual, las opciones de debug están bien configuradas. Mi Wordpress está actualizado a su última versión.

- **¿Saben si PHP  7 no reconoce la forma de debug desactivado como lo establece Wordpress?**
- **¿Conocen alguna manera de evitar esto?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finalmente he encontrado la causa del problema, al menos para este caso concreto. La comparto aquí por si se le presentase a alguien más.

Al cambiar la configuración en cPanel para que el servidor remoto use la versión 7 de PHP se crea un nuevo archivo `php.ini`en el directorio raíz (casi siempre este directorio se llama `public_html`).

En dicho archivo venían activadas las siguientes líneas:

```
display_errors = On
display_startup_errors = On
```

Según el Manual de PHP, [display_errors](http://php.net/manual/es/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.display-errors)

> Determina si los errores deberían ser impresos en pantalla como parte
>   de la salida o si deberían ocultarse al usuario.

Mientras que [display_startup_errors](http://php.net/manual/es/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.display-startup-errors)

> Muestra los errores que ocurren durante la secuencia de arranque de
>   PHP.

Al encontrarse activados en `php.ini`, el `define( 'WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', false);` de Wordpress no surtía ningún efecto.

Para evitar que los errores se muestren en pantalla, es necesario cambiar las dos líneas indicadas en `php.ini` del siguiente modo:

```
display_errors = Off
display_startup_errors = Off
```

y a continuación guardar los cambios en el archivo `php.ini`

**Nota:**
Los cambios en `php.ini` no tomarán efecto en una página abierta anterior a los mismos, para comprobar que efectivamente la impresión de errores en pantalla ha sido establecida a `Off` será necesario abrir una nueva pestaña en el navegador con la url de la página que antes imprimía el error, veremos que ya el mismo no es mostrado en pantalla.

Si volvemos al archivo wp-config.php y ponemos estos valores:

```
define( 'WP_DEBUG', true);
define( 'WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', true );
```

veremos que es posible activar-desactivar la notificación de errores en pantalla poniendo `true` o `false` en las mismas según el caso. O sea, todo funciona como antes.